# docker node image not running on localhost not even on docker machine ip

Tags: node.js, docker, localhost, docker-toolbox

I tried `docker run -p 8080:8080 myhub/node_project` server is running but i can't access it through browser not even with `docker-machine ip`

````
FROM node:alpine

COPY ./ ./
RUN npm install

ENV SERVER_PORT 8080 
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["npm","start"]```
````

No error is coming the console thing is printing but i can't access it through browser... `"this site can't be reached"`

Comment: What does the docker logs tells you ?

Comment: Check logs using `docker logs container-id`. `container-id` can be retrieved from `docker ps -a`

Comment: docker is running the node server properly